# OAuth2 flow for multiple resource servers

Tags: node.js, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

As I'm trying to create a unified OAuth2 system for an internal custom userbase system a question/problem arouse for which i couldn't find a fitting documentation:

In our microservice application/service structure we have several (web) application clients which usually have either a separate application server or contain all logic in the client. They are trying to access a network of microservices. Some API's are accessed directly while some are accessed through other services.

To protect these resources I envision a system similar to the following:
[image]

*The diagramm is mostly oriented at a Node.Js + Passport heavy structure but other technologies are in use in the real-life structure.*

Here the client/application server will handle the full login and authorization process directly using the OAuth2 Authorization Server. This will result in the client/application server having a valid access token.

Using this access token it can then access the API's by using the token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header of the request.

The API can then check this token by validating it against the Authorization server. Afterwards it could also temporarily save the token to not validate the token on each request but rather store it with a TTL.

When a service is internally accessing another service it should then just pass the Access token along so the next service can again validate it.

Is this the preferred flow/setup for such a case or am i making a mistake here?

Comment: Some folks use an API Gateway / API Router. If they are in the API Servers are in the same "security" domain there is no reason the access token could not be "passed" along.  This might be helpful: https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/